# How to calculate the RTP Timestamp for each packet in an audio stream

Tags: timestamp, audio-streaming, vlc, network-protocols, rtp

I read the RTP specification and I can't seem to get my head around the RTP Packet Timestamp. I tried to implement it in different ways in my server but I can't get the player to play it right.

The "wrong" behaviour I'm having here is that (*I use VLC player to play the RTSP url to my server*) I find the logs of the  player saying **"buffer way too late"** and **"wrong PTS value"**. Which means somehow that the audio frames arrives in a packets whose timestamp is not set right. I tried to implement the generation of the timestamp in different ways but no such luck.

I need some detailed resource or reference that really put my on the right track of understanding how to RTP timestamp works and gets generated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Audio and video timestamps are calculated in the same way.

Audio RTP payload formats typically uses an 8Khz clock. Then take the first audio sample containing e.g. 20ms and assign this timestamp t = 0. 20 ms is a 1/50 of a second, hence this equals a 8000/50 = 160 timestamp increment for the following sample. In the case of audio you can calculate the sample duration based on the sample rate, bits per sample, and number of channels. In the case of a live source, the sample might be timestamped already, and you simply have to translate the timestamp to an RTP timestamp.

Also, note that the RTP timestamp should start at a random number and not at zero.

A good reference for RTP in general can be found in the Colin Perkins book, [RTP - Audio and video for the Internet](http://csperkins.org/standards/rtp-book.html). While some of the information might be outdated, it will give you a good understanding of RTP.

Update:
The wall clock is determined by using the NTP timestamp in the RTCP SR, which tells you what time the RTP timestamp maps to i.e. RTP timestamp 160 = some date time. This is required e.g. for synchronisation to video where both RTP timestamps are using different random offsets. Of course the validity of the date/time depends on how the NTP timestamp is calculated on the sender and there is no guarantee that this reflects the actual date/time. You can sniff the traffic with wireshark which will tell you what date/time is represented by an NTP timestamp.

Update 2:

It depends on what the client is expecting and how the client is implemented. If you were writing your own RTSP client, it might suffice . E.g if you wrote a DirectShow source filter you could translate the RTP timestamp directly into a media timestamp and that would work. However since you're using an existing client, it could e.g. be that the client only uses synchronised RTP timestamps so in such a case it would *not* suffice. In summary it depends on the client implementation. I'm not sure what VLC is expecting.

Comment: Then where comes the part of the "Wall clock"?

Comment: So minimal implimentation of RTSP & RTP can ignore using RTCP and therefore NTP timestamp ( the wall clock )?

Comment: By minimal implementation, you're only writing the server? Client and server?

Comment: What type of audio are you streaming?

Comment: MPEG I,II layer 3 (AKA MP3). Using RFC 5219, dynamic RTP payload type (121).

Comment: I would suggest comparing your implementation to the open source live555 RTSP server available at http://www.live555.com. You can sniff the traffic as well as compare timestamp creation, packetisation, check how the timestamps are incremented, etc. In the past, comparing to working standard-conformant implementations has often helped me solve such issues.

Comment: Why should the RTP timestamp always start at a random number? Wouldn't that make it more confusing to figure out a current play point?

Comment: @Srevilo Random initial sequence number and timestamp increase security, as specified in [RTP RFC3550](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3550) _"The initial value of the sequence number SHOULD be random (unpredictable) to make known-plaintext attacks on encryption more difficult... The initial value of the timestamp SHOULD be random, as for the sequence number."_

Comment: $ \delta t = 8000 \frac{1}{s} \times \frac{1}{50} s $ which has no unit anymore, or am I missing something? Can this just be added to last timestamp like so: `t = t_{last} + dt`? This does not seem mathematically correct.